# Unable to make https request from k8s pod

Tags: ssl, https, kubernetes

I have a fresh kubernetes cluster (version 1.18) deployed using Rancher on a fresh Ubuntu Server 20.04. The problem I'm facing is that each https request made from any pod is failing with the following message:

```
curl -v https://pypi.org/simple/pip/
*   Trying 44.227.65.245...
* Connected to pypi.org (44.227.65.245) port 443 (#0)
* found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 692 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed
```

I've tested it using

```
kubectl create deployment hello-node --image=k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4
kubectl exec -it <pod_id> bash
```

I tried the same thing via ssh on the host system and everything was working properly. I also tried running standalone docker container (on the same machine) with the same image as pod (`docker run -it --rm k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4 bash`) and there were no problems here as well. So I'm guessing that this is something related to my kubernetes setup.

It happend only with https requests - http requests are working properly.

I tried to remove the cluster and prepare it from scratch but this didn't help.

**UPDATE:**

I'm receiving two types of messages, depending on the server I'm trying to connect:

```
root@hello-node-7bf657c596-smr2h:/# openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 -debug
CONNECTED(00000003)
write to 0xda15b0 [0xda1630] (305 bytes => 305 (0x131))
0000 - 16 03 01 01 2c 01 00 01-28 03 03 4e c0 cf d9 62   ....,...(..N...b
0010 - 58 6e 88 7b 28 7f e8 c1-62 c6 8f 23 60 86 b0 53   Xn.{(...b..#`..S
0020 - df 43 cd a7 58 52 bc 59-6a ae bf 00 00 aa c0 30   .C..XR.Yj......0
0030 - c0 2c c0 28 c0 24 c0 14-c0 0a 00 a5 00 a3 00 a1   .,.(.$..........
0040 - 00 9f 00 6b 00 6a 00 69-00 68 00 39 00 38 00 37   ...k.j.i.h.9.8.7
0050 - 00 36 00 88 00 87 00 86-00 85 c0 32 c0 2e c0 2a   .6.........2...*
0060 - c0 26 c0 0f c0 05 00 9d-00 3d 00 35 00 84 c0 2f   .&.......=.5.../
0070 - c0 2b c0 27 c0 23 c0 13-c0 09 00 a4 00 a2 00 a0   .+.'.#..........
0080 - 00 9e 00 67 00 40 00 3f-00 3e 00 33 00 32 00 31   ...g.@.?.>.3.2.1
0090 - 00 30 00 9a 00 99 00 98-00 97 00 45 00 44 00 43   .0.........E.D.C
00a0 - 00 42 c0 31 c0 2d c0 29-c0 25 c0 0e c0 04 00 9c   .B.1.-.).%......
00b0 - 00 3c 00 2f 00 96 00 41-c0 11 c0 07 c0 0c c0 02   .<./...A........
00c0 - 00 05 00 04 c0 12 c0 08-00 16 00 13 00 10 00 0d   ................
00d0 - c0 0d c0 03 00 0a 00 ff-01 00 00 55 00 0b 00 04   ...........U....
00e0 - 03 00 01 02 00 0a 00 1c-00 1a 00 17 00 19 00 1c   ................
00f0 - 00 1b 00 18 00 1a 00 16-00 0e 00 0d 00 0b 00 0c   ................
0100 - 00 09 00 0a 00 23 00 00-00 0d 00 20 00 1e 06 01   .....#..... ....
0110 - 06 02 06 03 05 01 05 02-05 03 04 01 04 02 04 03   ................
0120 - 03 01 03 02 03 03 02 01-02 02 02 03 00 0f 00 01   ................
0130 - 01                                                .
read from 0xda15b0 [0xda6b90] (7 bytes => 7 (0x7))
0000 - 15 00 00 00 02 02 28                              ......(
140080050284184:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:794:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 305 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1600154660
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

and

```
root@hello-node-7bf657c596-smr2h:/# openssl s_client -connect pypi.org:443 -debug
CONNECTED(00000003)
write to 0x24645b0 [0x2464630] (305 bytes => 305 (0x131))
0000 - 16 03 01 01 2c 01 00 01-28 03 03 0c 2b bf dc 71   ....,...(...+..q
0010 - d2 41 56 f3 40 e4 c5 3f-62 88 cf 2a a7 76 e4 a4   .AV.@..?b..*.v..
0020 - 08 96 13 89 30 13 fa 75-c9 2d 32 00 00 aa c0 30   ....0..u.-2....0
0030 - c0 2c c0 28 c0 24 c0 14-c0 0a 00 a5 00 a3 00 a1   .,.(.$..........
0040 - 00 9f 00 6b 00 6a 00 69-00 68 00 39 00 38 00 37   ...k.j.i.h.9.8.7
0050 - 00 36 00 88 00 87 00 86-00 85 c0 32 c0 2e c0 2a   .6.........2...*
0060 - c0 26 c0 0f c0 05 00 9d-00 3d 00 35 00 84 c0 2f   .&.......=.5.../
0070 - c0 2b c0 27 c0 23 c0 13-c0 09 00 a4 00 a2 00 a0   .+.'.#..........
0080 - 00 9e 00 67 00 40 00 3f-00 3e 00 33 00 32 00 31   ...g.@.?.>.3.2.1
0090 - 00 30 00 9a 00 99 00 98-00 97 00 45 00 44 00 43   .0.........E.D.C
00a0 - 00 42 c0 31 c0 2d c0 29-c0 25 c0 0e c0 04 00 9c   .B.1.-.).%......
00b0 - 00 3c 00 2f 00 96 00 41-c0 11 c0 07 c0 0c c0 02   .<./...A........
00c0 - 00 05 00 04 c0 12 c0 08-00 16 00 13 00 10 00 0d   ................
00d0 - c0 0d c0 03 00 0a 00 ff-01 00 00 55 00 0b 00 04   ...........U....
00e0 - 03 00 01 02 00 0a 00 1c-00 1a 00 17 00 19 00 1c   ................
00f0 - 00 1b 00 18 00 1a 00 16-00 0e 00 0d 00 0b 00 0c   ................
0100 - 00 09 00 0a 00 23 00 00-00 0d 00 20 00 1e 06 01   .....#..... ....
0110 - 06 02 06 03 05 01 05 02-05 03 04 01 04 02 04 03   ................
0120 - 03 01 03 02 03 03 02 01-02 02 02 03 00 0f 00 01   ................
0130 - 01                                                .
read from 0x24645b0 [0x2469b90] (7 bytes => 7 (0x7))
0000 - 15 03 03 00 02 02 28                              ......(
140284912154264:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:769:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 305 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1600154752
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

I found this two messages appearing together described here: https://blog.techstacks.com/2010/03/3-common-causes-of-unknown-ssl-protocol-errors-with-curl.html

> The Destination Site Does Not Like the Cipher You could be trying to
> connect to the site using an ssl cipher that the site is configured to
> reject. For example, anonymous ciphers are typically disabled on
> ssl-encrypted sites that are customer-facing. (Many of us set a
> blanket rejection policy on any SSL-encrypted web site—regardless of
> it's purpose.) The following command string "can" also result in the
> curl (35) error:
>
> curl --ciphers ADH-RC4-MD5 https://some_web_site.some_domain.com/
> Unfortunately, the type of error response you can get from curl
> depends largely upon the ssl server. On some sites, you'll receive the
> Unknown SSL Protocol error but on my techstacks-tools site, I get:
>
> curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3
> alert handshake failure

Another thing I dicovered is that I prepare the same environment on the DigitalOcean droplet and ther were no problems there.

My bare metal environment is not available from the world, it stands inside internal network - maybe this is somehow related?

I also tried to setup k8s using microk8s but the problem still occurs so this is probably not related to rancher but only to my machine setup.

YAML of the pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.42.0.8/32
    cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 10.42.0.8/32
  creationTimestamp: "2020-09-14T19:51:57Z"
  generateName: hello-node-7bf657c596-
  labels:
    app: hello-node
    pod-template-hash: 7bf657c596
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:generateName: {}
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:app: {}
          f:pod-template-hash: {}
        f:ownerReferences:
          .: {}
          k:{"uid":"dda770d0-3aa3-4fc9-97e1-c929fc3629e9"}:
            .: {}
            f:apiVersion: {}
            f:blockOwnerDeletion: {}
            f:controller: {}
            f:kind: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:uid: {}
      f:spec:
        f:containers:
          k:{"name":"echoserver"}:
            .: {}
            f:image: {}
            f:imagePullPolicy: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:resources: {}
            f:terminationMessagePath: {}
            f:terminationMessagePolicy: {}
        f:dnsPolicy: {}
        f:enableServiceLinks: {}
        f:restartPolicy: {}
        f:schedulerName: {}
        f:securityContext: {}
        f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {}
    manager: kube-controller-manager
    operation: Update
    time: "2020-09-14T19:51:57Z"
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        f:conditions:
          .: {}
          k:{"type":"PodScheduled"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastProbeTime: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:message: {}
            f:reason: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
    manager: kube-scheduler
    operation: Update
    time: "2020-09-14T19:51:57Z"
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: {}
          f:cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: {}
    manager: calico
    operation: Update
    time: "2020-09-14T19:52:01Z"
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        f:conditions:
          k:{"type":"ContainersReady"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastProbeTime: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
          k:{"type":"Initialized"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastProbeTime: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
          k:{"type":"Ready"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastProbeTime: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
        f:containerStatuses: {}
        f:hostIP: {}
        f:phase: {}
        f:podIP: {}
        f:podIPs:
          .: {}
          k:{"ip":"10.42.0.8"}:
            .: {}
            f:ip: {}
        f:startTime: {}
    manager: kubelet
    operation: Update
    time: "2020-09-14T19:52:01Z"
  name: hello-node-7bf657c596-smr2h
  namespace: default
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: ReplicaSet
    name: hello-node-7bf657c596
    uid: dda770d0-3aa3-4fc9-97e1-c929fc3629e9
  resourceVersion: "3468"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/hello-node-7bf657c596-smr2h
  uid: cf37b215-8269-42ce-9e70-750f9f862cac
spec:
  containers:
  - image: k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: echoserver
    resources: {}
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-9jlms
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: true
  nodeName: gepard
  priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  volumes:
  - name: default-token-9jlms
    secret:
      defaultMode: 420
      secretName: default-token-9jlms
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2020-09-14T19:52:00Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2020-09-14T19:52:01Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Ready
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2020-09-14T19:52:01Z"
    status: "True"
    type: ContainersReady
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2020-09-14T19:52:00Z"
    status: "True"
    type: PodScheduled
  containerStatuses:
  - containerID: docker://2d2ddbf42fc4e6634a782c7036cf4a9a1d9f50a3d847bb5444932c701cd8186e
    image: k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4
    imageID: docker-pullable://k8s.gcr.io/echoserver@sha256:5d99aa1120524c801bc8c1a7077e8f5ec122ba16b6dda1a5d3826057f67b9bcb
    lastState: {}
    name: echoserver
    ready: true
    restartCount: 0
    started: true
    state:
      running:
        startedAt: "2020-09-14T19:52:01Z"
  hostIP: 10.0.0.3
  phase: Running
  podIP: 10.42.0.8
  podIPs:
  - ip: 10.42.0.8
  qosClass: BestEffort
  startTime: "2020-09-14T19:52:00Z"
```

Firewall is disabled at the moment.

Comment: Any chance that you are using Proxy in your use case?

Comment: The only "proxy" is probably ingress but I'm not sure if it's participating in outbound traffic as well

Comment: You will have to [edit your question](https://serverfault.com/posts/1033455/edit) and include your Pod's YAML in order for anyone to help you, although I find "with the same image as pod and there were no problems" extraordinarily suspicious

Comment: I've added commands used for creating deployment and creating a docker container

Comment: @John This is not exactly what mdaniel has asked for. We need your Pod's YAML. Also, what is your firewall configuration (if present)?

Comment: I've added yaml, firewall is disabled

Comment: Are you using some kind of load balancer in your bare metal cluster?

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer below, not as part of the question where it will be missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP chose not to post an answer, but did say that they solved the problem:

> The problem was that there was were some strange domains added in the search part of `/etc/resolve.conf` on the host. And when I was trying to make a https request I have been redirected by DNS to some other server responding with plain http.
>
> Correcting the DNS settings solved the problem.